# What is the best way to transition between plank flooring laid on top of tile, and carpet?

Tags: flooring, tile, vinyl-flooring, ceramic-tile

I know any contractor may roll their eyes at this, but my sister recently replaced her vinyl plank flooring and saved the old flooring that was removed and gave it to me. My wife and I have been wanting to do something different with the tile floor in our home since we bought it a few months ago. Once we got this flooring for free I was thinking about going all in and removing all the tile to put in the new floor, but the more I think about it, the more removing the tile sounds horrible.

We are now thinking of laying the plank flooring on top of the tile. My main concern is just the transition between the flooring and the carpet, I am unsure of what kind of transition strips that could be used. The subfloor is concrete just in case that’s useful.

The following are a few images of the new flooring laying next to the carpet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

To sum it up:

1. What would be the best way to transition between the carpet and this flooring that would be installed on top of the tile?
2. Any recommendations for installing the flooring this way?
3. How dumb am I for wanting to take the shortcut and install the flooring on top of the tile?

Comment: How is your carpet transitioned to the tile?  Is there a tack strip there, or is it simply stapled to the subfloor?

Comment: @Huesmann I believe that it's just a tack strip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a "T" moulding or carpet transition strip, or a [hybrid like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/PERFORMANCE-ACCESSORIES-Boulder-0-75-in-T-x-2-37-in-W-x-78-7-in-L-Laminate-4-in-1-Molding-M4IN1-05923/318099636#overlay)

Answer (score 0):

Installing over tile is perfect.

The only problem with installing used, is that the planks were cut to fit the old room.

You will probably need to lay out the whole room twice, once loosely to see the fit and change planks around for best fit then can fully install the planks.

Should first measure sister's room and yours to see if you have or need extra planks to finish.

If need to buy new, make sure the planks match or can make a border around the room as an accent with a different colour/design.

There are multiple transitions around.  The type and style will become an opinion so not really liked on this site.  Google can give you and the other one who's opinion you go by to keep a happy home many choices.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a **threshold**.

Go to where you bought the floor and ask for their collection of transition thresholds, transition moldings, T-moldings, etc. They just have different names in different regions.

The vinyl plank manufacturer might even make one that matches the color of your new floor.